# Vagrant rsync (from cygwin) on windows 10 have fork memory error

Tags: cygwin, vagrant, fork, windows-10, rsync

I got quite irritating problem with vagrant rsync on my fresh installed windows 10 64-bit notebook.

```
> There was an error when attempting to rsync a synced folder. Please
> inspect the error message below for more info.
> 
> Host path: /c/Users/kryst/Projects/OSTSped/ostsped/ Guest path:
> /vagrant Command: rsync --verbose --archive --delete -z --copy-links
> --chmod=ugo=rwX --no-perms --no-owner --no-group --rsync-path sudo rsync -e ssh -p 2222 -o ControlMaster=auto -o
> ControlPath=C:/Users/kryst/AppData/Local/Temp/ssh.952 -o
> ControlPersist=10m -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o IdentitiesOnly=true
> -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -i 'C:/Users/kryst/Projects/OSTSped/ostsped/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key'
> --exclude .vagrant/ /c/Users/kryst/Projects/OSTSped/ostsped/ vagrant@127.0.0.1:/vagrant Error:       0 [main] rsync 1228
> C:\cygwin64\bin\rsync.EXE: *** fatal error in forked process - fork:
> can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has
> 0x400000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487    2512 [main] rsync 1228
> cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to
> rsync.EXE.stackdump
>       1 [main] rsync 4736 fork: child -1 - forked process 1228 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11 rsync: fork: Resource
> temporarily unavailable (11) rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14)
> at pipe.c(65) [sender=3.1.1]
```

I'm looking for an answer for few day now.
I tried to use 32 and 64 bit versions of cygwin, powershell, git bash.
I tried to update cygwin prefix to /cygdrive, /, or even to home directory (C:\User\kryst).
I tried to rebaseall.

Nothing solved a problem.

Actual versions of softwere:

> Vagrant 1.8.1
>
> Cygwin64 setup.exe version 2.873 (64-bit)
>
> Rsync 3.1.1-1
>
> OpenSSH 7.1p1-1

Comment: I'm having the same issue, it seemed to happen immediately after a Windows Update that has broken rsync for some odd reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like newer version of rsync  works fine

- Vagrant 1.8.5
- rsync  version 3.1.2

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I see you've tried 32-bit rsync - sorry, I've got nothing.

--

Could be some issue with Vagrant attempting to run 64-bit cygwin rsync from a 32-bit shell.

Reference: https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-07/msg00720.html

I'm experiencing the same issue, and I'm not sure how to solve this as yet.

Answer (score -2):

Try the workaround discussed here.

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3230

Comment: I was changing the Cygwin path too. It didn't helped. I need to find work around without vagrant box modification. We are working in team so we do not want to change configuration. It needs to work on every host.